# Dynamic forms with deform

Tags: python, pylons, colander, deform

Making form with deform and whould like to change the pageShema class depending on the choices made by the user.
Ex. if he selects option 1 from selectwidget, show him one set of fields, if case of other choice - another. 
How to do this?

Comment: Please add some code to the question show we get a hang what's going on

Answer (score 5):

You can use jquery and select with the "name" attribute.
Also, you can use the jquery "parent()" function to get the container of the input you are interested in showing/hiding.

For instance, in your schema do something like:

```
# This is the "<select>"
choices = (('yes','Yes'),
           ('no', 'No'))
bar = colander.SchemaNode(colander.String(),
                          widget=deform.widget.SelectWidget(values=choices))

# This is the input that should appear only when the "yes" value is selected
foo = colander.SchemaNode(colander.String())
```

Then, in your template, add somethig like:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

// ensure that the "foo" input starts hidden
var target = $("input[name=foo]").parent().parent();
target.hide();

$("select[name=bar]").on('change', function(){
    var valueSelected = this.value;
    if (valueSelected == "yes") {
      target.show();
    } else {
      target.hide();
    }
});



});
</script>
```

Comment: Very nice solution. Easy and smart.

Comment: Also for more comprehensive solution you can use something like https://github.com/miohtama/jquery-interdependencies